# Android help bubble around icon

Tags: android-layout, android

Hey guys i'm interested in how can i draw bubble to help the user do something with my app.
The same bubble like first start at a fresh android installation:

[image]

Comment: are you familiar with drawing tools like adobe illustrator, or have ready design layouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use this really cool [library](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/). Scroll down for a quickstart guide. By the way, if you're using Android Studio, the lib is on maven central just add  `compile 'be.novelfaces:novelfaces-showcase:0.2.1'` to your build.gradle dependencies.